# Pylance (VSCode) not displaying docstrings from my Rust (PyO3, Maturin) extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, rust, pylance, pyo3

In Rust

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

#[pyfunction]
/// Returns the answer to life, the universe, and all the rest
pub fn get_answer() -> usize {
  42
}

#[pymodule]
fn answers(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(get_answer, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Built with `maturin develop` in my current python environment, but also checked doing

`maturin build && pip install [wherever_that_wheel_went]`

In Python

```py
import answers

my_answer = answers.get_answer()
```

Now if you go to that python code in VSCode and hover over `get_answer`, the floating tip will *not* show the docstring. If I go to `ipython` and explicitly ask for `__doc__`, it's there, though.

What am I missing?

Comment: Quick note: If I switch the language server to Jedi, hovering does indeed show the docstring. But I want to get it to work in pylance...

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem since the end of last year. I was able to understand some of what that guy was saying by trying to read it as Latin with general success. Check your configuration settings, and the asker mentioned it might have been a mac issue, are you running mac? The fact that it works one place and not the other made me think it was the fault of Pylance but I know from experience that doesn't always follow. Will update answer with additional info as it arises.
[The question](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/discussions/2846)